# Is there a formula for the number of st-dags (DAG with 1 source and 1 sink) with n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, directed-graphs

I am looking at doing some basic validation on a database of st-dags. It would be useful to have:

1. A formula for the number of non-isomorphic st-dags with n vertices
2. A formula for the same with n vertices and p edges

Is there such a formula, and is there some literature (accessible to the non-mathematician) that might discuss any special properties of st-dags.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a formula, but a method of counting the graphs in OP faster than straightforward enumeration. It's superpolynomial in complexity (although sub-exponential).

Let's start with a recurrence for the number $a_n$ of labelled directed acyclic graphs on $n$ vertices: $a_0 = 1$, and for any $n \geq 1$
$$a_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{k - 1} {n \choose k} a_{n - k} 2^{k(n - k)}.$$
This is inclusion-exclusion principle applied to the number $k$ of sources in the graph. If we want the graph to have a single sink, we simply forbid the empty graph, and each of the new sources to not have any outgoing edges, resulting in a recurrence $a'_{0} = 1$, $a'_{1} = 1$, and for any $n \geq 2$
$$a'_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{k - 1} {n \choose k} a'_{n - k} (2^{n - k} - 1)^k.$$
Finally, to also have a single source, for the final set of sources we tweak the inclusion-exclusion weights: having $k$ new sources on the final step has weight $(-1)^{k - 1} \cdot k$. One can see that only the graphs with a single source are not cancelled out (and are counted once), thus
$$a''_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{k - 1} {n \choose k} k a'_{n - k} (2^{n - k} - 1)^k.$$

To count unlabelled graphs of this kind (we denote the numbers $b_n$, $b'_n$, $b''_n$ similar to the above), we combine the above approach with [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). Let $S_{n - 1}$ be the symmetric group acting on all $n$ vertices except for the unique sink. Then the number of unlabelled graphs is given by $b''_n = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} \sum_{\pi \in S_{n - 1}} a''_{\pi}$, where $a''_{\pi}$ is the number of labelled single source, single sink DAGs stabilized by the permutation $\pi$. Clearly, $a''_{\pi}$ depends only on the conjugation class (cyclic structure) of $\pi$, so we can write $a''_{\lambda}$ for a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) $\lambda$ of $n-1$.

With a slightly more sophisticated version of inclusion-exclusion, we have
$$a'_{\lambda} = \sum_{\varnothing \neq \mu \subset \lambda} (-1)^{|\mu|} {\lambda \choose \mu} a'_{\lambda - \mu} \prod_{i \in \mu} \left(2 \prod_{j \in \lambda - \mu} 2^{(i, j)} - 1\right).$$
The notation makes sense if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are treated as multisets. Similarly, one can show that
$$a''_{\lambda} = \sum_{\varnothing \neq \mu \subset \lambda} (-1)^{|\mu|} {\lambda \choose \mu} \omega(\mu) a'_{\lambda - \mu} \prod_{i \in \mu} \left(2 \prod_{j \in \lambda - \mu} 2^{(i, j)} - 1\right),$$
where $\omega(\mu)$ is the number of summands $1$.

The complexity of this solution is roughly $Poly(n) $[A000712](http://oeis.org/A000712)$(n) \sim Poly(n) exp(\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{n})$. This is an improvement of my initial approach from the comments to another answer, and, implemented in C++, produces [answers up to $n = 40$](https://pastebin.com/WPzNPUJq) in about two minutes.

To count unlabelled graphs of this kind with prescribed number of edges, one can ostensibly modify this approach to operate with generating polynomials $\sum_{e = \text{# of edges}} c_e x^e$ instead of numbers for values of $a_n$, $a_{\lambda}$, $a'_{\lambda}$, etc.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution (`a''`), but it did not work. Already for `n=2` I get 2 instead of 1. Can you maybe clarify/correct this?

Comment: @Simdi Do you refer to $a''_n$ or $a''_{\lambda}$? Please link your implementation so I can locate the problem.

Comment: I refer to the former. Here's my [implementation](https://pastebin.com/Qhkuaz2S).

Comment: @Simdi Ah but $a''_n$ count labelled graphs. There are indeed 2 graphs in question for $n=2$. In fact larger values produced by your code look correct to me as well.

Comment: Ah, yes you are absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a formula, but here is a sample SageMath code that generates all  st-dags on $n$ vertices:

```
from sage.combinat.gray_codes import product as gc_product

def stDAGs(n):
    if n==1:
        yield DiGraph([[0],[]])
        return
    elif n==2:
        yield DiGraph([(0,1)])
        return

    for P in Posets(n-2):
        H = P.hasse_diagram()
        for t in P.maximal_elements():
            H.add_edge(t,n-2)
        for t in P.minimal_elements():
            H.add_edge(n-1,t)

        E = list( set(H.transitive_closure().edges(labels=False)) - set(H.edges(labels=False)) )

        G = H.copy()
        C = G.canonical_label()
        CC = set(C.dig6_string())
        yield C


        for e,d in gc_product([2]*len(E)):
            if d>0:
                G.add_edge(E[e])
            else:
                G.delete_edge(E[e])
            C = G.canonical_label()
            dig6 = C.dig6_string()
            if dig6 not in CC:
                CC.add(dig6)
                yield C
```

Then the number of such graphs with $n$ vertices can be obtained as

```
def f(n):
    return sum(1 for d in stDAGs(n))
```

which for $n=1,2,\dots,8$ gives

```
1, 1, 2, 10, 98, 1960, 80176, 6686760
```

These counts do not appear in the OEIS - so it's likely that little is known about them. I've added them as [sequence A345258](https://oeis.org/A345258).

The above code can be easily adjusted to take into account the number of edges in each graph.

Comment: Next value 1129588960 .

Comment: @Brendan - you did not iterate over the actual graphs, did you?

Comment: I have not been a SageMath user in the past, so thank you for the sample code; it has been very useful and I have been tinkering with it since I saw your response. Seeing the time it took to get to the last value, I too am curious how you got that next value @Brendan . I did use some of the gtools in the Nauty package to iterate over the graphs and count them, doing my own cycle detection, but that is also slow for slightly higher values of n, which is what led me to search for a formula

Comment: @Marcel: I've slightly updated the code to speed it up. Now it goes over the posets of size $n-2$ and adds the source and sink to them. You can run the code online at https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I have a program for finding all the acyclic orientations of a graph.  I fed all the connected graphs with 9 vertices into it and counted how many of the outputs had only one source and one sink. I forget exactly but I think it only took a minute or two.  It could be done faster, but the next size up would be much harder.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Thanks for the explanation. Is your counting of acyclic orientations done by generating them all? At first glance, we can go over all permutations of vertices of an undirected graph, and view them as topological orderings of corresponding DAGs, but this way we will actually generate each DAG (possibly several times). Is there a shortcut?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Btw, can your approach gain speed up from generating DAGs without the single source/sink (ie. on $n-2$ vertices) and then adding these single source/sink as new vertices?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I made all 3404385285 connected DAGS on 9 vertices individually and counted their sources and sinks. It is not a good way but I had the programs already (check directg -a). It took 20 minutes. Starting with $n-2$ vertices would be much faster. Definitely 10 will be easy and perhaps 11 will be possible.

Comment: I programmed the $n-2\to n$ method and it does $n=9$ in 3 seconds.  The next one is 384610774696 in 10 minutes.  I will edit OEIS when I do $n=11$ which will take 30 or 40 hours.  The reason for the speed is that most of the acyclic orientations on $n-2$ vertices have trivial automorphism group, in which case the number of extensions can be calculated from the numbers of sources and sinks.

Comment: It's a fun combinatorial exercise to count these graphs efficiently. Here are my results up to $n = 25$: https://pastebin.com/Kn29mTFt

Comment: Up to $n = 30$ (took about 15 more minutes): https://pastebin.com/mkVNKChD

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov: Please add explanation of your approach as a new answer, and add your counts to OEIS A345258. Thanks! Btw, can your approach adjusted for a fixed number of edges as OP asked in the second question?

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov That is very impressive speed. This is not my field and while the second half of your answer with respect to unlabeled graphs loses me, I am looking forward to spending some time educating myself a bit and trying to fully understand it.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay You mention that "most of the acyclic orientations on n−2 vertices have trivial automorphism group, in which case the number of extensions can be calculated from the numbers of sources and sinks". Is there any literature that you could point me at that would elaborate on that point. Thanks!

Comment: @BrendanMcKay You refer to the -a option on directg above. I do not see that option on any version of directg that I have been able to find. Where can I get that version.

Comment: @Marcel  You are right. It is in the development version not released yet. If you write to me I can give it to you.

Comment: @Marcel I'll be happy to clarify any unclear parts, please feel free to ask.